# Must a Vulkan pipeline be recreate when changing the size of the window?

Tags: vulkan

As shown at https://vulkan-tutorial.com/code/23_texture_image.cpp:
Calling `createGraphicsPipeline()` to recreate the Pipeline when changing the window size, the dimensions are set in the code below.

```
VkViewport viewport = {};
viewport.x = 0.0f;
viewport.y = 0.0f;
viewport.width = (float) swapChainExtent.width;
viewport.height = (float) swapChainExtent.height;
viewport.minDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.maxDepth = 1.0f;

VkRect2D scissor = {};
scissor.offset = {0, 0};
scissor.extent = swapChainExtent;

VkPipelineViewportStateCreateInfo viewportState = {};
viewportState.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_PIPELINE_VIEWPORT_STATE_CREATE_INFO;
viewportState.viewportCount = 1;
viewportState.pViewports = &viewport;
viewportState.scissorCount = 1;
viewportState.pScissors = &scissor;
```

If the scene contains lots of materials, changing the window size will recreate all materials, which is very time consuming. Can I modify their `VkRect2D` and `VkViewport` directly without recreate the pipeline?

Answer (score 18):

You'd have to make the scissor and viewport *dynamic state* in all the pipelines where they will depend on the window size. To do this:

1. Fill in `VkGraphicsPipelineCreateInfo::pDynamicState` with `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_VIEWPORT` and `VK_DYNAMIC_STATE_SCISSOR` in `VkPipelineDynamicStateCreateInfo::pDynamicStates`.
2. After binding a pipeline with dynamic viewport and scissor state, call `vkCmdSetViewport` and `vkCmdSetScissor` to set the current viewport and scissor. You don't have to call these again after every binding each pipeline, only for the first dynamic-state pipeline in a command buffer, and after a dynamic-state pipeline if the previous pipeline didn't use dynamic state.